# Why tables are not created in the database?

Tags: python, django

please help to solve the problem.

I created a model with related fields (foreignkey). but I can not create a table in the database.

models:

```
class Status(models.Model):     
    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=40, 
        blank=False,
    )                   


class Gender(models.Model):     
    gender = models.CharField(
        max_length=10, 
        blank=False,
    )   


class UserProfile(User):            
    nickname = models.CharField(
        'Отображаемое имя',
        max_length=30, 
        blank=False,
    )
    gender = models.ForeignKey(
        Gender,
        verbose_name='Пол',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        #default=Gender.objects.get(pk=1),
    )
    status = models.ForeignKey(
        Status,
        verbose_name='Статус',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        #default=Status.objects.get(pk=1),
    )
```

the problem is that after running the console command:

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

I get the following error message:

```
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: drummersaransk_userprofile
```

initial_data.json:

```
[       

    {
        "model": "drummersaransk.Status",
        "pk": 1,
        "fields": {
            "status": "Барабанный бог"
        }
    },
    {
        "model": "drummersaransk.Status",
        "pk": 2,
        "fields": {
            "status": "Профессиональный барабанщик"
        }
    },  
    {
        "model": "drummersaransk.Status",
        "pk": 3,
        "fields": {
            "status": "Барабанщик"
        }
    },  
    {
        "model": "drummersaransk.Status",
        "pk": 4,
        "fields": {
            "status": "Барабанщик в прошлом"
        }
    },  
    {
        "model": "drummersaransk.Status",
        "pk": 5,
        "fields": {
            "status": "Играю на другом инструменте, но барабанщик в душе"
        }
    },  
    {
        "model": "drummersaransk.Status",
        "pk": 6,
        "fields": {
            "status": "Сочувствующий"
        }
    },      


    {
        "model": "drummersaransk.Gender",
        "pk": 1,
        "fields": {
            "gender": "Ж"
        }
    },
    {
        "model": "drummersaransk.Gender",
        "pk": 2,
        "fields": {
            "gender": "М"
        }
    }   
]
```

command python `manage.py test UserProfile` outputs: ImportError:

> No module named 'UserProfile'

Comment: did you change the models after the tables were initially created?

Comment: I was changing the existing table. and then tried to delete the table and run syncdb. moreover, I initialize the model through initial_data.json (edited the post)

Answer (score 0):

here you have bug:

```
class UserProfile(User):            
    nickname = models.CharField(
    'Отображаемое имя', #bug, is it verbose_name?
    max_length=30, 
    blank=False,
)
```

fix:

```
class UserProfile(User):            
    nickname = models.CharField(
    verbose_name='Отображаемое имя',
    max_length=30, 
    blank=False,
)
```

Comment: Did you create new database? `python manage.py syncdb --traceback` you'll get more info.

Comment: after the command python manage.py syncdb --traceback is displayed in the console the same error message:
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: drummersaransk_userprofile

Comment: Have you deleted the old database and next created new?

Comment: yes. im deleted DB and created new DB. 
wherein the command python manage.py test UserProfile outputs: ImportError: No module named 'UserProfile'

Answer (score 0):

Django's `syncdb` command will never execute SQL that will destroy data; since creating and editing foreign keys is one such operation, you cannot use `syncdb` for this.

If you drop the tables, `syncdb` will recreate them.

You can use [database migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/) if you are using django 1.7, or use [`south`](http://south.aeracode.org) which provides migrations for django versions < 1.7

As you are developing right now, it might be easier to simply drop the database and start fresh.

Also keep in mind that you need to [define your file encoding](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#unicode-literals-in-python-source-code) if you are using anything other than latin-1 in your code, and you are still on Python version 2.

Comment: I tried delete all tables from the database. but the problem remained

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete your database then create it again and use syncdb

or use south migration

```
python manage.py schemamigration UserProfile --auto
```

Comment: I tried delete all tables from the database. but the problem remained

Comment: delete the entire database and create it again. Did you try schemamigration ?

Comment: did you add userprofile in your setting installed apps?

Comment: "did you add userprofile in your setting installed apps".
why??

Comment: the error says no module name userprofile so i guess your module name is userprofile but it doesn't find it so maybe u missed it somwhere. Did you try schemamigration?